# how can I read xml file and store the values into a json object using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, xlsread

how can I read xml file and store the values into a json object using angularjs.please suggest me how to do this using angularjs.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: didnt find any examples for reading xml file using angularjs can U provide me any links for that, that will be helpfull.

Comment: How are you going to read xml file? Read using HTTP? File from user input (input type=file) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<body ng-controller='xlreaderController'>

  <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  <p>{{data}}</p>

</body>



app.controller('xlreaderController', function($scope) {
         $scope.data = 'none';
            $scope.add = function(){
              var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
                  r = new FileReader();
              r.onloadend = function(e){
                $scope.data = e.target.result;
                //alert($scope.data);
                console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.data));
                var ks = (JSON.stringify($scope.data)).split("\n");
                $.each(ks, function(k){
                     console.log(k);
                });
              };
              r.readAsBinaryString(f);
            };
    });
```